# Extract multiple sentences with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I've been trying to extract text from a file, the file is *similar to json* and I've tried `JSON.Parse` but always returns error. I think it is not in a proper json format, so I want to do it with plain regex.

```
<ref *2> MessageEmbed {
  message: <ref *1> Message {
    channel: DMChannel {
      type: 'dm',
      deleted: false,
      id: '644589216793362433',
      recipient: [User],
      lastMessageID: '644728116396163073',
      lastPinTimestamp: null,
      messages: [Collection [Map]],
      _typing: Map {}
```

I need to extract the *id* value like `64458...` and the *messages* value `"[Collection [Map]]"`. How can I accomplish this with **regex**?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. Read here for guideline to post a question that is a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be the best way, but maybe you'd be interested in looking into,

```
id:\s*'(\d*)'|messages:\s*(\[.*\])
```

```js
const regex = /id:\s*'(\d*)'|messages:\s*(\[.*\])/gm;
const str = `<ref *2> MessageEmbed {
  message: <ref *1> Message {
    channel: DMChannel {
      type: 'dm',
      deleted: false,
      id: '644589216793362433',
      recipient: [User],
      lastMessageID: '644728116396163073',
      lastPinTimestamp: null,
      messages: [Collection [Map]],
      _typing: Map {}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WSJkhh/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/WSJkhh/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]